# MQCONN error 2540 Invalid Channel Name

Tags: visual-c++, ibm-mq

The IBM documentation for WebSphere's MQ error codes says that the channel name was incorrect.  Channel name?  Nowhere in the doc for MQCONN says anything about channel name.  It asks for the name of the Queue Manager, which I have done, and verified is correct.

It is tempting to think of "channel" as a synonym for "queue".  But before you can connect to a specific queue, you have to connect to the Queue Manager first, and that is the where I am encountering the error.

What does "channel" mean in this context?

Thank you

Comment: "where I am encountering the error" Channels are part of queue managers. So, if you were not able to access the queue manager, then you wouldn't be able to get to this error

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting in Client mode (i.e. a network connection) and in order to connect via the network from your application to the queue manager, there will be some configuration to say how to do this. For example, an IP address and a port number. Along with this, there will be a channel name. You might be doing this using a MQSERVER environment variable, or the Client Channel Definition File (CCDT) for example. If the MQCHLLIB and MQCHLTAB environment variables are set, they point to the CCDT that is being used.

It is in this configuration that you will find the channel name, and then you must see whether there is a channel of TYPE(SVRCONN) defined on your queue manager with the same name as the one in your client application configuration.

To see more details about the error, look in the AMQERR01.LOG file both on your client machine and on the queue manager. There you will see more detailed errors about the channel name in question.

Comment: This application was given to me to make some changes.  In order for me to test the changes, I had to copy the project to a remote VM and run it there (because only that VM has access to the server?).  On that VM, there is a utility that lets me inject files onto a queue.

Comment: I injected a file onto the queue successfully, but when I ran the application, it failed to connect to the Queue Manager, error code == 2, reason code == 2068.  I was told to move the executable to another network path.  The call to MQCONN() returned 2, 2540 in that location, even though I was running it on the same VM.

Comment: The environment variables on that VM that start with 'M' all look like they are associated with MQ: MQCHLLIB (points to a different project), MQCHLTAB (which has some ASCII text, but is useless to me without knowing where which data might be), MQ_FILE_PATH, MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH, and MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH.

This issue may be moot (for now), since the task of testing my changes has been reassigned to another developer with more experience in corporate environment.  Still, I wouldn't mind knowing how and why I went wrong, since I love knowing new things.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A channel is not a queue. It is a logical communication link.

[def of a channel](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=types-channels)

I suggest you to ask or look yourself into the MQ server error log because the error returned by the client could not be enough to understand the problem.

ex log returned by an IBM ACE integration server trying to connect to IBM MQ:

```
2023-09-01 09:21:13.505324Z: [Thread 25425] (Msg 2/2) BIP2677E: Failed to make a client connection to queue manager 'RVI_QM_ACE' using hostname 'hostname hidden' on port '1414': MQCC=2; MQRC=2540.
```

You know it is a 2540 (MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME) but not much more.

If you look into the MQ error log:

```
 CommentInsert2(hostname hidden (ip hidden)(1414))
                   
AMQ9520E: Channel not defined remotely.

EXPLANATION:
There is no definition of channel 'RVI_QM_ACE' at the remote location.
ACTION:
Add an appropriate definition to the remote hosts list of defined channels and
retry the operation. The remote host is 'hostname hidden (ip hidden)(1414)'.
----- cmqxrfpt.c : 772 --------------------------------------------------------
```

So now you know that the client is requested to open a connection to hostname (here hidden) with ip (here hidden) port 1414 and the channel 'RVI_QM_ACE' does not exist at the MQ side.

Using the MQ Explorer and looking into the channels it is possible to check if the channel does exist (or not).

If it is a test server then create the channel yourself or ask an IBM admin at your site to help.